# Can't get browsers to display a div with some justified text at the same width

Tags: html, css

Below is the CSS style this div is using. The  div itself
is nested within a table. Basically IE displays this differently
from FireFox and Chrome. I like the IE rendering better
and it seems more inline with what I am seeing in dreamweaver,
where as firefox and chrome will display the div wider then
it's in IE and dreamweaver for some reason.

I haven't designed anything in a while but it's sad to see
that we still have these rendering differences between browsers,
is this still the case with HTML5/CSS3 ?

```
.Class420 {
    font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#000;
    line-height:30px;
    background-color:#F5F5F5;
    width:400px;
    text-align:justify;
    padding:15px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the current output and expected output (screen shot or fiddle)?

Comment: Likely, the issue is caused by the environment around the div so we'd have to see that environment to give you any idea what's going on.  To your question, there are fewer rendering differences today than there were several years ago, but there are still many.  If you are using standardized features, you can usually find a "proper" way to do it that works in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

```
is this still the case with HTML5/CSS3 ?
```

Yes. And it's still Internet Explorer which is holding everyone back.